# Seeing the URQL cache

Tags: reactjs, react-native, caching, graphql, urql

I'm looking at customizing how URQL caches API responses by userId, but having trouble figuring this out. I'd like to be able to console log the entire URQL cache, to check what is being stored. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the urql graphql dev tool [link for chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/urql-devtools/mcfphkbpmkbeofnkjehahlmidmceblmm) and you can see  [how to use it here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qQnLllEMqN8)

Basically. after installing the urql graphql dev tool. You can head on to your browser dev tools. Where you will see this.

[image]

and for every cache updates. you can see the tree for the query object in the cache and their corresponding values.

example

[image]

Comment: Maybe it's too late. but I hope it helps anyone in same need

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32996175)